# Percentile in list

Tags: r, list, percentile

I have the following list (h):

```
> h
[[1]]
[1] 0.9613971

[[2]]
[1] 0.9705882

[[3]]
[1] 0.9503676

[[4]]
[1] 0.9632353

[[5]]
[1] 0.9779412

[[6]]
[1] 0.9852941

[[7]]
[1] 0.9852941

[[8]]
[1] 0.9816176
```

I would like to add a new column that will calculate the percentile of each number in the list.
I tried to use the following and I get errors:

```
perc.rank <- function(x, xo)  length(x[x <= xo])/length(x)*100


perc.rank <- function(x) trunc(rank(x))/length(x)

trunc(rank(h))/length(h)
```

In addition, I would to know given a number such as 0.9503676 (the third number) or its number (3) how can I know what is his percentile?

Comment: Does your data have to be in a list? Dataframe or datatable might be easier to work with.

Comment: Hi Heroka, the data can be transformed to another type of data structure such as dataframe. However, its source is list so it will be good to stay in the list. But as as I said dataframe is good enough.

Comment: You should provide the structure of the list elements. Here, they appear to be `vector`s, which do not have columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this more efficiently by first converting your list into a vector as follows:

```
h <- unlist(h)
```

Next, create a function to find the percentile, which you can easily do by creating an empirical cdf function for your list as follow:

```
perc.rank <- ecdf(h)
```

To find the percentile for any number, example the third number, do the following:

```
perc.rank(0.9503676)
```

This will work even if the number isn't in your list. eg. perc.rank(0.91) should give you the percentile for 0.91 and you can also pass multiple numbers to the function like perc.rank(c(0.950,0.913,0.6))

Comment: Thanks FelixNNelson. If I have the number (position) in the list (such as 3) how can I know what is the percentile of this number  (position)?

Comment: @Avi Assuming the number position is 3 and your list is in a variable called h, then to get the percentile of the 3rd element of h, execute perc.rank(h[[3]]).

Answer (score 2):

Converting to dataframe will make things easier. Here is one solution

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10))
df%>%mutate(percrank=rank(x)/length(x)*100)

             x percrank
1   1.56254900      100
2  -0.52554968       10
3   0.16410991       70
4   0.95150575       80
5   0.01960002       60
6  -0.22860395       30
7   1.43025012       90
8  -0.15836126       40
9  -0.01150753       50
10 -0.39064474       20
```

Comment: Instead do df<-data.frame(x=unlist(h))

Answer (score 2):

This adds two list elements to the current list `h`.

The second list element is the percentile as you have it.

The third list element is an ordinal rank number.

```
h <- list(.9613971, .9705882, .9503676, .9632353, .9779412, .9852941, .9852941, .9816176)

# create percentiles
rnk1 <- rank(unlist(h)) / length(h)

# ordinal rank
rnk2 <- rank(unlist(rnk1))

# combine the original lists with the two additional elements
res <- mapply(c, h, rnk1, rnk2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
res
[[1]]
[1] 0.9613971 0.2500000 2.0000000

[[2]]
[1] 0.9705882 0.5000000 4.0000000

[[3]]
[1] 0.9503676 0.1250000 1.0000000

[[4]]
[1] 0.9632353 0.3750000 3.0000000

[[5]]
[1] 0.9779412 0.6250000 5.0000000

[[6]]
[1] 0.9852941 0.9375000 7.5000000

[[7]]
[1] 0.9852941 0.9375000 7.5000000

[[8]]
[1] 0.9816176 0.7500000 6.0000000
```

Lookup function by ordinal rank

```
perc.rank <- function(x, xo) {
  x[[match(xo, sapply(x, "[[", 1))]]
}

perc.rank(res, .9779412)   
[1] 0.9779412 0.6250000 5.0000000
```

Which shows that .9779412 is ranked number 5